# $dom = new DOMDocument; show one line

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm doing a  DOMDocument where i get information from a website, i'm trying to get the text inside of the `<p> </p>` , the code works fine but the fact is that the website has many `<P>` codes so i get all the information,  i just want the information of the first `<p>`, 
the `<p>` has not id classes so it doesn't help please check the code and help me to know how to get only the first `<p>`

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com');

$dom = new DOMDocument;  
@$dom->loadHTML($html);  

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p'); 

forsearch ($links as $link){  
echo $link->nodeValue; 
echo $link->getAttribute('') , '<br>'; 
$goal = $link->nodeValue;
}
```

the code works fine but it shows all the text, i just need the first `<p>` not all.

Comment: Your question would greatly benefit from using punctuation and paragraphs.  And `i` alone is supposed to be `I`.  `I'm` => `I am`.  Add a sample page you are trying to extract information form, and point out the expected result.  We will be able to test your code, and the proposed solution.

Comment: thanks for your help :)  
that site it's a good example   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthquake   ,,,  if you do that, you get all it's <p> , i just need the first one :)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php shows that the return for getElementsByTagName is a DOMNodeList object.  This object (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) can be accessed via the item method to get a DOMNode.  So extract the first one from the DOMNodeList and you are done.  DOMNode provides methods to get the content (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php), `$textContent`

Comment: that's the thing i'm trying but the php manual has not a good explanation of this ;/ so i have no idea how it could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the first paragraph element you can do it like that:

```php
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://example.com'));

$paragraphs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
echo "Content of first paragraph: {$paragraphs->item(0)->nodeValue}\n";
```

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "<!DOCTYPE html> <html class="client-nojs" lang="en" dir="ltr"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"/> <title>Earthquake - Wik in /home/web/public_html/test.php on line 4
Content of first paragraph:

Comment: Sorry my fault, I've changed my code :)
But you should always check codes and not just copy&paste.

Comment: sorry bro , i get this  :(
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag bdi invalid in Entity, line: 350 in /home/web/public_html/test.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag bdi invalid in Entity, line: 388 in /home/web/public_html/test.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag bdi invalid in Entity, line: 499 in /home/web/public_html/test.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag bdi invalid in Entity, line: 501 in /home/web/public_html/test.php on line 5

Comment: Just add `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` after `$doc = new \DOMDocument();`
This disable libxml errors, but keep in mind that you have to fetch possible errors byself (refer to the php documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php).

Comment: Paste the URL you try to get the needed element.

Comment: Just checked, the code works, the first paragraph is an empty paragraph!

Comment: i get all paragraphs with the code use showed at the begining .

Comment: Yes, but if you take a detailed look, then on the page are the first 2 paragraphs without content! So you need to check this and go to the next, this can be done in an foreach loop:

`$doc = new \DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthquake'));
$paragraphs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');

$i = 0;
foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    $i++;
    if ($paragraph->getAttribute('class') === 'mw-empty-elt') continue;
    echo "Paragraph {$i}: {$paragraphs->item($i)->nodeValue} \n";
    break;
}
`

Comment: looks good, can you give me the code in the edit text cause i can't get it from the answer box

Comment: Serious? Just mark the code and copy the code, where is the problem? Alternative you can Copy it by manually typing the code in your preferred editor while reading ;)

Comment: so, sorry sr, i'm so noob,,  now it works ... really thanks for your help <3  :'v